# Stop duplicates being added to an array

Tags: php, arrays

OK I'm querying the database and populating an array with the results but I don't want to get duplicates.

```
    $start = date('c', $row['start_time']);

    while (strtotime($end) < $row['end_time']){
        $title = 'Teacher Available';
        $color = '#a3a3a3';             
        $end = date('c', strtotime($start) + hoursToSeconds($row_Branch['session']));
        $allday = ($row['allDay'] == "1") ? true : false;
        if (in_array($start, $input_arrays) == false){
            $input_arrays[]= array(title => $title, start => $start, end => $end, color => $color, allDay => $allday);
        }
        $start = date('c', strtotime($end));
    }
```

In my way of thinking this should not add a new entry to the array if there is already an entry with the same $start but for some reason it adds it anyway.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: it would be useful if you add your query string.  and solve it using the `group by`

Comment: You assign the variable after you search for it, which makes it look for the variable set in the last iteration of the while-loop, not the current iteration.

Comment: group by won't work because the start and end values in the database may not be equal.  but I don't want double ups where they overlap.

Comment: @Qirel that is exactly correct, each time it loops through $start should be the same as the last $end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$start` is set to the string returned by `date('c',...`).  `$input_arrays` is an array where each element is also an array.

So, when you test `in_array($start, $input_arrays, true)`, it will test if your string is equal to each of the arrays within the `$input_arrays` array.  A string is always NOT equal to an array, especially since you specified `true` which means the types must match.

There's a number of ways to fix this, depending on what you want, including ...

```
    ...
    if ( !array_key_exists($start, $input_arrays) ){
        $input_arrays[$start]= array(title => $title, start => $start, end => $end, color => $color, allDay => $allday);
    }
    ...
```

EDIT:  To get `$input_arrays` with keys 0,1,2,... as required by your calendar module, add this statement just after your `while` loop:

```
$input_arrays = array_values($input_arrays);
```

Comment: I get the same result regardless whether I use strict checking or not.

Comment: edited to remove the strict checking, just to clarify for others.  I'm not looking for an array key, I'm looking for other entries in the array that have the same 'start'.

Comment: Aaron, the simplest solution (May even be the only solution) is to assign the $start as the array key, which then allows simple `array_key_exists` checks. Try not to over-complicate un-complicated tasks.

Comment: @Aaron, it is not the strict checking that is the error.  As you say, it fails with or without strict checking.  The problem is that "in_array" is not as smart as you think it is.  It only gets passed the value of $start, it doesn't know that that value should be associated with the name "start" and so should look for a key named "start" in the arrays within the $input_arrays array.  It is much simpler, more generic, and so more generally useful than that.  The key (pun!) change that I suggested was to use $start as key of $input_arrays so that you can test for duplicates in each iteration.

Comment: @BareNakedCoder Ah ok now I understand what you were suggesting, I'm not sure if that will work with the calendar module the data is being past to but I will test and see.

Comment: @BareNakedCoder Well your suggestion works beautifully for the array but as I feared the calendar won't read the array like this, it is simply looking for a numbered array.

Comment: @Aaron.  I didn't know $input_arrays need to be in a specific format.  A minor modification makes that possible.  I'll add that as a new answer ...

Comment: @Aaron.  See answer below; it adds 2 statements to your orig code.  Or, you could fix the answer above by adding " $input_arrays = array_values($input_arrays); " just after your while loop.  It'll return an array with the same values but with keys 0,1,2,... as required by your calendar module.

Answer (score 1):

`$start` is set to the string returned by `date('c',...`).  `$input_arrays` is an array where each element is also an array.  A non-empty string is always NOT equal to a non-empty array so your `in_array` always returns false.  Try this ...

```
$start = date('c', $row['start_time']);
$startTimesAlreadyAdded = [];
while (strtotime($end) < $row['end_time']){
    $title = 'Teacher Available';
    $color = '#a3a3a3';             
    $end = date('c', strtotime($start) + hoursToSeconds($row_Branch['session']));
    $allday = ($row['allDay'] == "1") ? true : false;
    if ( !in_array($start, $startTimesAlreadyAdded) ) {
        $input_arrays[] = array(title => $title, start => $start, end => $end, color => $color, allDay => $allday);
        $startTimesAlreadyAdded[] = $start;
    }
    $start = date('c', strtotime($end));
}
```

This will leave you with `$input_arrays` with keys 0,1,2,... as required by your calendar module.